# Get message from the FTP command

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I would like to know if it exist a way to get in a ascii file the message from the FTP function in batch. 
I have this instruction in a .CMD file:

> ftp -i -s:mescommandes.txt

in mescommandes.txt :

```
open "ipserver"

"user"

"pwd"

ascii

lcd "working\directory"

cd "storage\directory"

mput  monficA*.txt

mput  monficB*.txt

mput  monficC*.txt

quit
```

I would like to save in an ASCII file messages like: 226 Transfer complete.

Comment: Have you tried 'ftp -i -s:mescommandes.txt > out.txt'?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked !! Thank you very much Ilya

Answer (score 1):

Use command `ftp -i -s:mescommandes.txt > out.txt` to send output of ftp to file out.txt.